# How to display when the function is called javascript parameter prompt

Tags: javascript, xcode, webstorm

Call function in javascript when prompted how to make it function? I am using the IDE webStorm. As in Xcode use Objective-C when the function is called when the parameters are prompted to highlight the default parameters, I can switch to the default position by the Tab key parameters, I want to enter pass parameters.[image: WebStormcallJavascriptfunciton]

[image: XcodecallObjective-Cfunction]

Answer (score 1):

Hit `Cmd+P` inside brackets to see the parameters info; see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/viewing-method-parameter-information.html